# Model for a Class that describes other Classes

Tags: java, reflection, metadata

I've got some problem that i can't figure out for a loong time.

I'm building web app in core-plugin architecture.
Plugins provides some functionality by methods. For example:

```
public void doSomething(Input input){
    // Some functionality
}
```

The Input class can be basically anything. For example:

```
public class Input{
    private String text;
    private List<String> textList;
    private InnerField inner;
    private List<InnerField> innerList;
} 
public class InnerField{
    private String text;
    pirvate Integer number;
}
```

The core module is collecting all methods of plugins and provides them to webpage user so the user can pick a method and set input data.

I know how to use java reflection api and get into metadata of methods and classes. The problem is with figuring out the structure of Class that would describe the Input and in same time store the data of Object.

In other words. I want to create a Class let's say InputData that i can pass to frontend which will:

- build form based on fields declaration
- fill form based on data

This InputData on submit would be serialized to json and saved in DB and, of course, should be mapped to original Input class so we can pass it to the plugin method.

I was thinking about something like this:

```
public class InputField{
    private String className; //java.lang.String, some.package.CustomClass
    private boolean variable; // if true, the strVal is a reference to other object (stored in map)
    private String strVal; //value parsed to String if it's basic type like String, Integer, Boolean
    private List<InputField> fields; //list of inner fields if it's complex type
}
```

And this would be good enough but only if the Input class would not have List types in it.

The one last kicker is that each field (even Input object itself) can be a referece to some variable.
So for example the user provided some values for Input class and want to reuse that so in form he just provides a name of the variable that it refers to. At the runtime when we invoke the plugin method the processor istead of parsing this json to data would search for data referenced by the variable name.

I know.. probably none of you know what i'm talking about but i'm in so awfull mindset that i can't even explain it well.

I am hoping that somone will kind of understand me and put me on the right tracks. Maybe someone had similar issue?

Edit: As requested below is short describtion what i really wanr to achive:

Basically i need a generic class in core module that will describe objects that are not known at compile time. From objects of this generic class i should be able to:

- get metadata for building dynamic form in frontend and fill this form with data
- map this object to original object (the one that is described by the generic class
- generic class should be serializable (for example to json)

I "only" need help in generic class structure.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are actually asking here.  Please ask a specific question ... preferably one that isn't asking for an opinion.

Comment: I eddited the post.

Comment: Once again, you have not asked a specific question.  You are basically describing a problem and saying "help me".  Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Ok i get it now but i really don't know how to be more specific on this and break this into smaller programming issues so i guess i'm on my own.

Comment: Well, yea, maybe, but I'm still unclear what kind of help you actually need here.  You already seem to have a rudimentary class structure in the classes you showed us.  And the rest is ... well ... coding problem.  (On the other hand, if you are looking for *opinions* ... mine is that this is not going to give a user interface that is particularly usable.  A programmer would prefer a scripting language.  A non-programmer will be baffled.)

Comment: The structure i provided was not quite what i was looking for and it was more about figuring out right structure of model than coding problem. The app is for engineers that are comfortable with technical stuff but not necessarily programming. Scripting could be to much for some of them. Thanks for opinion though :)

Answer (score 0):

As i realized, thanks to Stephen, answers for "question" i asked would not be any help for anyone as i doubt someone would face exact same issue.

However, i figured out the right way to go for me. Frankly asking a question here was helpfull because trying to explain what i want achive made me think outside of the box.

Anyway. Earlier i was trying to keep Class definition along side with Object data in one Meta-Class. I separated those so i have class which holds definition about input class:

```
@Data
public class ObjectDefinition{

    private String name;

    private String path; // for example $root.myField.text, $root.listField[$idx].number

    private Class type;

    private boolean collection;

    private boolean basicType;

    private List<ObjectDefinition> fields; //only if this object is not basic
    
}
```

The values will be stored in a list of objects of class:

```
@Data
public class Field {

    private String type;

    private String path;

    private String value;

    private String var;

    private boolean isCollection;

    private int collectionSize;
}
```

Ugly? Maybe. Not efficent? Probably. Most important it will work and meets my requirements.